# Is there a way to change failed login message on Linux systems (GDM)?

Tags: gdm, gdm3

On CentOS7, when a login attempt fails, a message

> Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.

is prompted. Is there a way to change this message? Also, is there a way to customize the message depending on the cause of the login failure? e.g. User not found, wrong password.

Comment: Whether or not the message can be changed I don't know. However I doubt there is a way to specify the login failure - revealing the failure reason for a malicious user would compromise the system security.

Comment: I assume by "a way" you don't include changing the source code and recompiling, right?